# How to solve $\left(\int_0^x t\sin(\frac{1}{t})dt\right)’_{x=0}$?

Tags: calculus

> How to solve $\left(\int_0^x t\sin(\frac{1}{t})dt\right)’_{x=0}$?

I’m not sure if I can use Newton-Leibniz Theorem 
$$\dfrac{d}{dx}\left(\int_a^xf(t) dt=f(x)\right)$$ because $f(x)=x\sin(\frac{1}{x})$ is undefined where $x=0$. Is it correct that let $f(0)=0$?

Comment: What are the conditions required to apply the theorem ?

Comment: The problem becomes more interesting if $t\sin(1/t)$ is replaced by $\sin(1/t)$ or $\cos(1/t)$. In this case the discontinuity at $0$ can not be removed and it requires some more manipulation to get the answer as $0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fundamental theorem of calculus only requires your function to be continuous over a closed domain ; in our case $f : t \mapsto t \sin(1 / t)$ is continuous on $(0, a]$ for any $a$, so we can instead use the continuous continuation $\widetilde{f}$ which is equal to $f$ over $\mathbb{R}^*_+$ and is $0$ for $x = 0$ (this is indeed the limit of $f$, as $\sin$ is bounded by $1$). It turns out that $f$ and $\widetilde{f}$ have the same integral over any closed interval of $\mathbb{R}^*_+$ ; can you take it from there ?

Comment: I see. But use the fundamental theorem I get the $F’(x)=x\sin{\dfrac{1}{x}}$. To get $F’(0)$, can I let $x\to 0$, directly?

Comment: Absolutely, you can just do that.

Comment: Because $f$ is continuous? Thanks a lot.

Comment: As I said, $f$ is not continuous over a closed interval because it is not defined at $0$. Instead, we consider the continuation, which is in turn defined at $0$ and stays continuous. Since this continuation is continuous and only differs from $f$ at one single point, both integrals are equal and you can apply the fundamental theorem of calculus to the continuation, leading to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Hint. Let $F(x):=\int_0^x t\sin(1/t)dt$, then  $F(0)=0$ (note that  $\lim_{t\to 0^+} t\sin(1/t)=0$ which means that the integrand function is bounded in a neighbourhood of $0$). Hence $F$ is a continuous function and
$$\left(\int_0^x t\sin(1/t)dt\right)’_{x=0}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{F(x)-F(0)}{x-0}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{x}\int_0^x t\sin(1/t)dt.$$
Now we may use L'Hopital rule (and Newton-Leibniz Theorem  for $x\not=0$). You may also use the Mean Value Theorem: for any $x\not=0$ there is $t_x$ between $0$ and $x$ such that
$$\frac{1}{x}\int_0^x t\sin(1/t)=t_x\sin(1/t_x).$$

P.S. More generally if a derivative of a continuous function has a limit, it must agree with that limit. See [prove that $f'(a)=\lim_{x\rightarrow a}f'(x)$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/257907/prove-that-fa-lim-x-rightarrow-afx)

Comment: Mh, how can the limit be evaluated ? Certainly not by L'Hospital...

Comment: This is wrong. $t \sin(1 / t)\underset{t \rightarrow 0}{\rightarrow} 0$, because $sin$ is bounded by 1 for any t.

Comment: @Matrefeytontias Thanks, I corrected the typo.

Comment: Use Lhospital rule then it follows $F’(0)=(\int_0^x t\sin{\dfrac{1}{t}})’$, it is just the question itself.

Comment: No, by Hopital we evaluate $\lim_{x\to 0}F'(x)$!

Comment: @闫嘉琦 See my P.S.

Comment: @Yves Daoust "Certainly not by L'Hospital... " why not?

Answer (score 0):

Let , $$f(x) = \int_0^x t\sin(1/t)dt$$

$$\left(\int_0^x t\sin(1/t)dt\right)’_{x=0}=f'(0)=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{x}\int_0^x t\sin(1/t)dt.$$

But since, $|\sin(1/t)|\le 1$

$$\left|\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{x}\int_0^x t\sin(1/t)dt\right|\le  \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{x}\int_0^x tdt = \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x}2 =0$$

Thus, $$f'(0)=\left(\int_0^x t\sin(1/t)dt\right)’_{x=0} = 0$$

Also see here for similar problem: [Compute $f'(0)$ and check if $f'$ is continuous or not](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2526370/compute-f0-and-check-if-f-is-continuous-or-not/2526393?noredirect=1#comment5221530_2526393)